# PowerBuilder Standard-Script Encryption

Tags: encryption, powerbuilder

So this is the situation. Our company has its own standard codes and windows (for commonly used routines and for inheriting) that we use in developing applications. These "standard codes and windows" is saved in its own library (pbl). Normally when we deploy our software to the client we just compile it to pbd's and exe's, but this time our client wants also the source code of the software. The thing is we don't want our standard codes and windows to be visible when we give the source code to the client. So is there a way to encrypt (shield, hide etc...) the codes.

I hope someone can point me to where should I start researching.

Comment: If the client wants the source code he probably doesn't want a encrypted version.

Comment: @sth: If I understand correctly, while giving the application source code to the client the OP would like to keep a corporate module as a black box. I don't know if that point can be defended from a provider / client perspective... (= if the client *buy* the product, the provider should provide the *whole* source code ?)

Answer (score 2):

The .pbls contain sources, resources and binaries, while the .pbd contain no source.

If you do not want to leak any source code, just give the .pbd and .exe files.

If you do want to give the source code of the application minus the source code of your standard library, give the all .pbl files but your standard library, and give the .pbd of the standard lib. Thus your client will even be able to recompile the app (providing that the standard lib object are called by, but do not call other pbjects from the application).

Please note that like Java, the PowerBuilder objects *can* be decompiled from binaries with the right tool.

I am not aware of a mean to encrypt PB source code, but there is the possibility to obfuscate the objects through [PB-Protect](http://www.pb-protect.com/). I never used it and I cannot tell more about it.

Answer (score 0):

If they're actually looking for insurance should you disappear, perhaps a code escrow service might be acceptable?  My company escrows our source at customer request as a paid-for contract line item, I think with Iron Mountain.